# Can I use LDA topic modeling if I do not know the number of topics

Tags: python, python-3.x, lda, topic-modeling

I have more than 100k .txt files with newspaper issues and I need to define the lexical field of protectionism. Nonetheless, the newspaper issues treat very diverse subjects and I cannot know the total number of topics. Can I still use LDA topic modeling to find the lexical field or is there another method (maybe supervised learning)?

Comment: LDA is unsupervised learning and hence should be applied when you essentially doesn't know the number of topics. If you are asking what number you need to put in the parameter, just go with how many topics you want!!

Comment: Ok that seems clearer! thanks! So for the parameter I would only put 1 if I want to have a lexical field of protectionism or do I need to "guess" the number of total topics in all the files?

Comment: So, essentially LDA just makes a corpus of all your text files, and see the topic which have been talked about most and will give you `n` words of it. So, if you select one it may or may not be the one you are looking. Go for a higher number, see in each topic what types of words you are getting and then subsequently increase or decrease!!

Comment: Alright, got it thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You probably can, but have a look at this [CorEx](https://github.com/gregversteeg/corex_topic) idea. This works very nice and gives you the opportunity to guide the groups by supplying a set of anchor words (so you can call it semi-supervised leraning).

You could give it ["protectionism", "tarifs", "trade wars", ...] as ancors for one topic and even try to push articles that are non related to the topic you are interested in into a second topic by defining ancor words that have nothing to do with your topic e.g. ["police protection", "custom features", ...]

The notebooks supplied are really excellent and will have you up and running in no time

Comment: Amazing, I'll try this out! Thank you so much!